# Spotify API token issue

Tags: python, web, spotify

as the title suggests, I want to get in the form of JSON file the contents of my Spotify library, mainly liked songs and playlists. Spotify provides a web API for that, but I am not experienced with web applications.

However I am experienced with Python, and I try to implement what the Spotify for Developers Documentation on the site suggests with Python.

Firstly, I have to request for an Access token which is used in every HTTP request. I follow the instructions  [here](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/code-flow/), and *Request User Authentication* section, the GET request that I do for getting the callback responds with

```
'{ "error": { "status": 401, "message": "No token provided" } }'
```

The thing is that I send this request in order to get the Access token.
This is my code:

```
import requests


uri_redirect = 'http://localhost:8888/callback'
authorize_endpoint = 'https://api.spotify.com/authorize'
request_authorization_parameters = {'client_id': 'here I give my client id',
                                    'response_type': 'code',
                                    'redirect_uri': uri_redirect,
                                    'scope': 'user-library-read playlist-read-private'}
r_auth = requests.get(authorize_endpoint, params=request_authorization_parameters)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Cheers!

Comment: I know this could be annoying, but first I would make sure that you have the correct token and client ID. I have had this exact issue before and it said there was no token when it was really just a wrong token.

Comment: I haven't used any token. From what I understand I have to get the token in order to be able to send HTTP requests. What I posted is the first step of the procedure that I follow. Am I missing former steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all, it was a careless mistake. I used wrong URL for the authorization endpoint.

The request must be sent to `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize` instead of `https://api.spotify.com/authorize`.

Following the rest of the documentation, I had no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `scope` should be a list []

Comment: The URL that it builds is slightly different, but I get the same error. The URL that is built from the code in my OP is `scope=user-library-read&scope=playlist-read-private` while using the list is `scope=user-library-read+playlist-read-private` (I just put here the relevant part of the URL). I am not very familiar with web applications and I don't know if that is a significant change.